# Angular Js - LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I'm new to Angular, 
I have a simple question to relay to LocalStorage in AngularJS.
I have a json file to get data to the DOM and I already have the LocalStorage.getItem working and display on the console.

Right Now I need to figure out how to get that LocalStorage into the Dom after clicking a simple button.

This is my controller for the file:

```
angular.module('stock').controller('checkListController', [
    '$http',
    'checkListService',
    function checkListController($http, checkListService) {
        'use strict';

        var self = this;

        this.checkList = [];
        $http.get('api/checklist.json').then(function (result) {
            self.checkList = result.data.items;
        });

        this.checkListMissing = [];
        $http.get('api/checklist-missing.json').then(function (result) {
            self.checkListMissing = result.data.items;
        });


        var addList = [];
        var missingItemList = [];
        this.addItem = function (item) {
            addList.push(item);
            localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(addList));
            missingItemList = addList;
            console.log(missingItemList);
        }

    }
]);
```

Does this makes any sense? 
Thank you all

Comment: how about using `self.missingItemList`, then creating a binding in your HTML like normal?

Comment: Thanks Claies, 
Actually I tried it and it didn't work. Maybe I'm not doing it right.

Comment: @cristian Oliveira my resolution working fine and correct as per your query pls vote if its working fine

Comment: how can i include self.missingItemList as a binding? Using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    angular.module('stock').controller('checkListController', [ '$http','$window', 'checkListService', function checkListController($http,$window, checkListService) { 'use strict';

        var self = this;

        this.checkList = [];
        $http.get('api/checklist.json').then(function (result) {
            self.checkList = result.data.items;
        });

        this.checkListMissing = [];
        $http.get('api/checklist-missing.json').then(function (result) {
            self.checkListMissing = result.data.items;
        });


        var addList = [];
        var missingItemList = [];
        this.addItem = function (item) {
            addList.push(item);
            localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(addList));
            missingItemList = addList;
            console.log(missingItemList);
        }
    //this function will call when a button will click
        $scope.showJsonContent = function() {
                         $scope.jsonDataFrmLclStorage = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem("item"));
                     }

    }
    ])

HTML need for button which will call the showJsonContent function expose in scope would be below
<button data-ng-click="showJsonContent()" >Show Content</button>
```

this will display the entire object of json data

{{jsonDataFrmLclStorage}}

Comment: thank for your answer. 

adapting to my code, it's something like this: 

var addList = [];
        this.addItem = function (item) {
            addList.push(item);
            localStorage.setItem('item', JSON.stringify(addList));
            console.log(addList);
        }, 

        this.showMissingContent = function() {
                        self.showMissingContent = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('item'));
                    }

Comment: Then, i need to click this button: 
<button class="switch-checklist" ng-click="showchecklist = !showchecklist" ng-show="!showchecklist">Finish Checklist</button>

my button already had a ng-click to swith between the main checklist and the result, this is the button for that. I need to change my ng-click and add your " data-ng-click="showMissingContent()" "?

I did that, and it didn't work. 
I've made a video to explain what i'm doing: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4th9c8ZmBNA&feature=youtu.be